# Minimize this IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was going to post this in code golf, but I think it may be better suited here.  I'm not really interested in scoring it beyond accepting the best answer.

I'm wanting to minimize this series of `IFS`, if possible or necessary.  I'm brand new to javascript/coding, but it just seems like there may be some redundancy here.

```
if(activeCell.getRow() > 2 && activeCell.getColumn() == 1){
  activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjItemValidationRule);
  activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjSubItemValidationRule);
  activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjActionValidationRule);
  activeCell.offset(0, 4).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);

} else if(activeCell.getRow() > 2 && activeCell.getColumn() == 2){
  activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjSubItemValidationRule);
  activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjActionValidationRule);
  activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);

} else if(activeCell.getRow() > 2 && activeCell.getColumn() == 3){
  activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjActionValidationRule);
  activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);

} else if(activeCell.getRow() > 2 && activeCell.getColumn() == 4){
  activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is off-topic for both Code Golf and Code Review. The purpose of the site is not to really "compete" for best or shortest answers. The purpose is to get meaningful feedback on a complete program or module that has substantial context and motivation. Please see [ask].

Comment: Ok.  Didn't mean to abuse the site or anything. I'm just learning and thought maybe there is an easier way.  But, on code golf, the tags do say specifically that it's a competition.  But I'll remove the post regardless.

Comment: So on Code Golf, you can make a competition, but just asking people to minimize an arbitrary `if` statement will likely be closed as [off-topic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See their [how to ask](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and, typically, PCG questions should go through the [sandbox for proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) and be vetted.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the tip!  I did try to find something on posting etiquette and looked everywhere but the question mark icon.  So thank you for bringing that to my attention.  I'll be sure to check there first before posting anything in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `activeCell.getRow()` is repeated in all ifs, the only way I see of refactoring your code without overcomplicating the script is the following:

```
if(activeCell.getRow() > 2){
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjItemValidationRule);
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjSubItemValidationRule);
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjActionValidationRule);
    activeCell.offset(0, 4).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);

  } else if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjSubItemValidationRule);
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjActionValidationRule);
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);

  } else if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjActionValidationRule);
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);

  } else if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

*EDIT:*
As it has been pointed out by "esote" in the comments of this answer, you could add a switch statement to improve the readability, the code would be:

```
if(activeCell.getRow() > 2){
  switch(activeCell.getColumn()){
    case 1:
      activeCell.offset(0, 4).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);
    case 2:
      activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);
    case 3:
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);
    case 4:
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(projectTasksAdjTaskValidationRule);
      break;
  }
}
```

If you have any doubt about how switches work, see on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: You should also use a switch statement for `activeCell.getColumn()`, rather than a bunch of if-else-if's

Comment: Inside the first if block, you can use a map of  `var actions = { 1: () => { ...}, 2: () => {...}}; actions[activeCell.getColumn()]();` You need to handle the scenario when there is no action defined.